# Tengo unos errores en el login que deseo crear

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

> Notice: Undefined index: usuario in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto1TAP\Login\validar.php on line 2
>
> Notice: Undefined index: contraseña in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto1TAP\Login\validar.php on line 3
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
> bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto1TAP\Login\validar.php on line
> 16
>
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto1TAP\Login\validar.php on line 18
>
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto1TAP\Login\validar.php on line 22 Warning:
> mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool
> given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto1TAP\Login\validar.php on line 36

Son los errores que me sale al querer dar a funcionar mi login y mi codigo de validar. php es:

```
<?php
$usuario=$_POST[‘usuario’];
$contraseña=$_POST[‘contraseña’];
session_start();
$_SESSION[‘usuario’]=$usuario;

//include(‘db.php’);

$conexion=mysqli_connect(“localhost”, “root”, “”,“bdiescorza”);

$consulta=“SELECT*FROM usuario where usuario=’$usuario’ and contraseña=’$contraseña’”;
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

if($filas [‘IdTipo’] ==1) //Directora o sub Directora
{ header(“location: directora.html”); }
else

    if($filas['IdTipo']==2)   //Profesor o profesora
    {  header("location:profesor.html"); }
else{
?>

<?php
include(“index.html”);
?>

<h1 class=“bad”> ERROR AL INGRESAR </h1>
<?php
}

mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Y de del index.html que creo que aquí no hay problema pero igual lo muestro:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Login </title>
<link rel=“stylesheet” href=“css/login.css”>
<link rel=“stylesheet” href=“css/cabecera.css”>

</head>
<body>
<form action=“validar.php” method=“post”>
<h1> Sistema de Login</h1>
<p> Usuario <input type=“text” placeholder=“Ingrese su nombre” name=“usuario”></p>
<p> Contraseña <input type=“password” placeholder=“Ingrese su contraseña” name=“contraseña”></p>
<input type=“submit” value=“Ingresar”>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: De partida me parece que esa comilla es el error, usa la comilla de este tipo $usuario=$_POST[‘usuario']; tambien $consulta="SELECT*FROM..."

Comment: Tu código está lleno de esta comilla ‘  y de esta comilla “ y ninguna de ellas es válida, PHP admite sólo la comilla simple y la doble comilla de toda la vida, las que tienes en esta parte por ejemplo son las comillas correctas: `if($filas['IdTipo']==2)   //Profesor o profesora
    {  header("location:profesor.html"); }`  debes igualar el código usando esos dos tipos de comillas.

Comment: Vale vale voy a corregir esas cosas